# Which method is proposed for split date string?

Tags: java, string, datetime

I have a `String` instance as following format:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

and I want split any element of it to a integer variable. for sample:

```
String date_time = "20080519145436";
```

By above string result must be:

```
int year  = 2008;
int month  = 05;
int day  = 19;
int hour  = 14;
int minutes  = 54;
int second  = 36;
```

I found two way for solve this issue:

1. using a `SimpleDateFormatter` and fetch elements.
2. using `subString()` method of `String` class.

My question is: Which way is proposed? There are another ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the date formatting mechanisms in [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

For example:

```
final DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern ( "yyyyMMddHHmmss" );
final DateTime date = parser.parseDateTime( "20080519145436" );
int year = date.getYear();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there simple way without extra library?

Comment: JodaTime performance is perfectly fine. Naturally you'd precreate the formatter if you're going to use it multiple times within a class or method.

Comment: @MJM Do you have ANY performance issues? I guess not... This is far better (in readability and maintenance) than `int month = (int) (d / 100000000L % 100);`

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use SimpleDateFormat

```
String date_time = "20080519145436"; 
        SimpleDateFormat df =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Date d= df.parse(date_time);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't even think about using String.subString(). A date is not a String and you shouldn't try to handle it as a String, because you will have absolutely no sanity checks on your input. You could enter any 14 digit input, and your algorithm would split that into nonsense date parts, like month=42. Using SimpleDateFormatter, JodaTime or any other algorithm specialized on date objects will throw an exception in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
    long d = Long.parseLong("20080519145436");
    int year = (int) (d / 10000000000L);
    int month = (int) (d / 100000000L % 100);
    int day = (int) (d / 1000000L % 100);
    int hour = (int) (d / 10000L % 100);
    int minutes = (int) (d / 100L % 100);
    int second = (int) (d % 100);
```

as for options I think #2 is faster

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(date_time.substring(0, 4)); 
...
```

because SimpleDateFormat is known to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

using a SimpleDateFormatter and fetch elements.